# After about 10 minutes in car: throat burns; no smell

Tags: ford, focus, egr

Ford Focus LXT DCI 1753cc Diesel Estate MK11. Mileage: 57000.

P0489 Diagnostic code. EGR valve has been replaced. Vehicle drives beautiful. After driving for about 10 minutes, throat begins to burn, so dues rear of tongue. No smell. What could be going on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Your throat burns? Along with your tongue? Why in the hell are you driving this car? Holy smokes, hope you're still alive!